# Use PhantomJS with pjscrape to scrape dynamically generated web content

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, dynamically-generated

I just started using pjscrape and try to run a sample scraper provided on http://nrabinowitz.github.io/pjscrape/#overview and called the following command in terminal but it gave me errors:

```
$ phantomjs /Applications/nrabinowitz-pjscrape-600e20a/pjscrape.js my_config.js
```

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'phantom.args.length')
>
> /Applications/nrabinowitz-pjscrape-600e20a/pjscrape.js:834 in global
>   code ^Z
>
> [6]+  Stopped                 phantomjs
>   /Applications/nrabinowitz-pjscrape-600e20a/pjscrape.js my_config.js

But then I figured out it's probably because in pjscrape.js file, it uses `phantom.args.length` which has already been replaced by `system.args` in newer phantomJS. So I modified the original pjscrape.js:

```
var system = require('system');
// make sure we have a config file
if (!system.args.length) {
// die
console.log('Usage: pjscrape.js <configfile.js> ...');
phantom.exit();
} else {

// load the config file(s)
system.args.forEach(function(configFile) {
    if (!phantom.injectJs(configFile)) {
        fail('Config file not found: ' + configFile);
     }
    });
 }
```

Then I ran the same command, but it gave me the following errors:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
>
> undefined:0 in injectJs RangeError: Maximum call stack size
>   exceeded.
>
> undefined:0 in injectJs
>   /Applications/nrabinowitz-pjscrape-600e20a/pjscrape.js:844   :0 in
>   forEach RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
>
> undefined:0 in injectJs
>   /Applications/nrabinowitz-pjscrape-600e20a/pjscrape.js:844   :0 in
>   forEach RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
>
> /Applications/nrabinowitz-pjscrape-600e20a/pjscrape.js:850 in global
>   code   :0 in injectJs
>   /Applications/nrabinowitz-pjscrape-600e20a/pjscrape.js:844   :0 in
>   forEach RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
>
> undefined:0 in injectJs
>   /Applications/nrabinowitz-pjscrape-600e20a/pjscrape.js:844   :0 in
>   forEach FATAL ERROR: No suites configured

Now I really don't know what's wrong. My my_config.js(where I defined my scraper using pjscrape) looks like this:

```
pjs.addSuite({
// url to scrape
url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_towns_in_Vermont',
// selector to look for
scraper: '#sortable_table_id_0 tr td:nth-child(2)'
});
```

Can someone help me figure out how to fix problem?
Eventually, I want to be able to scrape a website where the content I need is generated by a javascript calculator which only take one set of inputs and generate one result at a time. But I also want to enter thousands of different inputs to the calculator and get a huge table of results.

Answer (score 3):

[`system.args`](http://phantomjs.org/api/system/property/args.html) returns *all* command line arguments, *including* the original script, whereas `phantom.args` only returned the command line arguments after the script file. Basically, it goes into an infinite loop, because it keeps injecting the `pjscrape.js` file until the maximum call stack size is reached.

Solution: splice off the first argument: `system.args.splice(1).forEach...`

Comment: YOU MADMAN! THIS WORKED!